# Use of Acronyms in LaTeX

Tags: latex, acronym

I'm trying to add a list of all acronyms I use at the end of my document.

This is an example of what I'm trying:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{mel}

\bibitem[Sigurdur]{mel}
Sigurdur Sigurdsson,\emph{'Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients: An Evaluation of     Robustness of MP3 Encoded Music'}, Informatics and Mathematical Modelling, Technical   University of Denmark

\end{thebibliography}

\begin{acronym}{H2O}
\acro{H2O}[$H_2O$]{water}
\end{acronym}
```

I want to print this page after the Bibliography page.

At the beginning of the document I'm adding the following line:

```
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
```

and within the document I try `\ac{H2O}`, but I didn't get it to print the acronym H2O, nor the acronym list.

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: `[belongs-on-typesetting-overflow]` ;)

Comment: He's saying he doesn't believe that LaTeX is a programming language, a topic we tend to cover here with every LaTeX question, always ultimately deciding that yes, it is a language, and yes, this is the right place to ask the question.

Comment: @mmr: I didn't know that there was precedence in favor of LaTeX being programming related, and I humbly capitulate from that discussion. However, I still believe the OP might get better results from asking the question in a LaTeX forum/mailing list.

Comment: In re LaTeX on SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/where-should-a-question-about-latex-usage-go . It stays.

Answer (score 5):

Your example doesn't compile correctly (you should have square brackets for the argument to the acronym environment); here's a minimal example that should help to get you started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}
Acronym: \ac{H2O} \\
Again: \ac{H2O}
\begin{acronym}[H2O]
\acro{H2O}[$\mathrm{H_2O}$]{water}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds like you know stuff about latex and the acronym package. Hope you can answer a quick question. Some of my acronyms fail to write the full acronym at first usage, just showing gibberish, for example '@!?@!?@ss(SS)' for `\acro{ss}[SS]{Signal Strength}`. The only thing I could find in the log was: `Package acronym Info: Label 'acro:ss' newly defined as it shall be overridden
although it is yet undefined on input line 9.`

Answer (score -3):

I'm not familiar with the acronyms package but I suspect that your problem is this: you have defined the acronym at the end of the document and tried to use it prior to its definition.

I haven't even got a good guess about why your acronym list was not printed.

If this is no use and you decide to post again, include the error messages that LaTeX generated -- or tell us that it didn't generate any.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try defining the acronym before using it, however, when I use the bibliography package I define the bibliography at the end of the document and I'm able to use it anywhere.

Comment: Hi tried defining the acronym before using it, but I still don't get it to be printed. I don't get any error message.

Comment: Hmm, I'm out of ideas, it worked for me, defining the acronym first.  You did run LaTeX twice on the document didn't you ?  I guess you have to do that with the bibliography package (??) as you do when building a ToC or index.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "...run LaTeX twice on the document..."?

Comment: actually like any back-references in latex, they will be resolved if you compile them twice.